# Macros is opening a template and not creating a new one

Tags: excel, vba, macos, ms-word

I have a macros that is triggered from Excel, opens a Word template and populates the bookmarks. It currently is set to open the template. I need it to create new from the template so that my staff don't save over it all the time.

I've tried troubleshooting it with other people that have asked the same question, however, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong so seeking help.

```
Sub CreateProposal()
Dim STPNumber As String
Dim c As Range
Dim templateName As String

If Len(Trim$(Range("E1").Value)) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Please select template first...!", vbCritical, "Error"
    Exit Sub
End If

If Len(Trim$(Range("L1").Value)) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Please enter STP Reference number...!", vbCritical, "Error"
    Exit Sub
End If

STPNumber = Range("L1").Value
Set c = Range("D:D").Find(What:=STPNumber, LookIn:=xlValues)
If c Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "STP Number is not present...!", vbCritical, "Error"
    Exit Sub
End If

templateName = ActiveWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & Range("E1").Value & ".dotx"
If Not FileOrFolderExistsOnMac(templateName) Then
    MsgBox "This template is not present... please select correct template", vbCritical, "Error"
    Exit Sub
End If


If Range("E1").Value = "FEE PROPOSAL TEMPLATE (Impact)" Then
    CreateTemplate1 templateName, c.Row
Else
    CreateTemplate2 templateName, c.Row
End If

'show success message
MsgBox "Word document has been created successfully", vbInformation, "Success"
End Sub

Private Sub CreateTemplate1(tPath As String, r As Integer)
Dim wdApp As Object
Dim wdDoc As Object

On Error Resume Next
Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
If wdApp Is Nothing Then Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
On Error GoTo 0

wdApp.Visible = True
'wdApp.DisplayAlerts = False
Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Add(FileName:=tPath)

With wdDoc
    .BookMarks("STPNumber").Range.Text = Range("L1").Value
    .BookMarks("ProposedUse").Range.Text = Range("L" & r).Value
End With
End Sub


Function FileOrFolderExistsOnMac(FileOrFolderstr As String) As Boolean
'Ron de Bruin : 1-Feb-2019
'Function to test whether a file or folder exist on a Mac in office 2011 and up
'Uses AppleScript to avoid the problem with long names in Office 2011,
'limit is max 32 characters including the extension in 2011.
Dim ScriptToCheckFileFolder As String
Dim TestStr As String

If Val(Application.Version) < 15 Then
    ScriptToCheckFileFolder = "tell application " & Chr(34) & "System Events" & Chr(34) & _
     "to return exists disk item (" & Chr(34) & FileOrFolderstr & Chr(34) & " as string)"
    FileOrFolderExistsOnMac = MacScript(ScriptToCheckFileFolder)
Else
    On Error Resume Next
    TestStr = Dir(FileOrFolderstr & "*", vbDirectory)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not TestStr = vbNullString Then FileOrFolderExistsOnMac = True
End If
End Function
```

Nothing happens when I try to change it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `Filename` argument for the `Documents.Add` method. Use the `Template` argument instead, like this.

```
Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Add(Template:=tPath)
```